# How to show total number of errors within a page in primefaces message?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, message

I'm using jsf 2.1 and Primefaces 3.3. I want to show the total number of errors within a page at the top of the page using `<p:message>`.

Please give me advice for how to do it and it will be helpful if you can explain with an example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to count specific messages (e.g. only errors). you can do something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MessageCount {

    public int getFatal() {
        return countMessages(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
    }

    public int getError() {
        return countMessages(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    }

    public int getWarn() {
        return countMessages(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN);
    }

    public int getInfo() {
        return countMessages(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    }

    private int countMessages(FacesMessage.Severity severity) {
        Iterator<FacesMessage> iterator = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages();
        int count = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FacesMessage msg = iterator.next();
            if (severity.compareTo(msg.getSeverity()) == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

And in your jsf page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{messageCount.error}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use `<p:message/>` ?

Try this

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:length(facesContext.messageList)}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this. You can for example add `inputHidden` element to form, and add `p:message` for that input hidden field:

```
<p:messages for="justForErrorCount"/>
<h:inputHidden id="justForErrorCount"/>
```

In your backing bean you can do some check and add message:

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList() != null &&
        !FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().isEmpty()) {

    String message = "You have " + 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() + " errors";
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("justForErrorCount",
        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message);
}
```